# Как получить значение параметра из RGB формата

Tags: python, алгоритм

мне нужно из подобных карт получать значение параметра в каждой точке. я пробовал переводить значение ргб в серый цвет, но всё равно выходное значение даже логически не соответствует искомому параметру[image: карта, из который мне нужно получать значение параметра]
На входе у меня только эта карта(значение RGB в каждом пикселе). я ищу как мне перевести эти данные в значение параметра, который описывает данная карта.

Comment: Вопрос слишком абстрактный. Укажите, чем и  как пользуетесь для работы с изображением

Comment: Вы про цифры на шкале слева или про что? Чему у вас `RGB` не соответствует?

Comment: Шкала слева. Если значения не совпадают с конкретными на шкале, надо строить кусочно-линейную функцию.

Comment: Тут это явно `colormap`, причём я такую прям не нашёл в точности. https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html

Comment: Такие создаются в гидродинамических симуляторах. но, к сожалению, нигде нет алгоритма их построения(чтоб выполнить обратную задачу).

Comment: Карта имеет легенду, на ней обозначено, какой именно цвет чему соответствует. Цвет имеет три компонента, параметр скалярный, всего четыре. Соберите из каждой клетки легенды четырёхмерный вектор, концы этих векторов соедините по вкусу линиями. Можно отрезками прямых, а можно и единой сглаженной кривой. Или каждые 4 точки отдельным кубическим сплайном, причём, в каждой следующей четвёрке новая точка только одна, а одна старая исключается, потом сплайны порезать на куски между каждыми двумя точками и усреднить куски сплайнов между одними и теми же точками.

Comment: В любом случае точки надо как-то соединить. Теперь у нас есть цвет точки на карте, ищем ближайший к нему цвет на полученной линии, подставляем его в уравнение этой линии (кусочное или единое) и решаем его относительно параметра.